# Delphi 10 Seattle do NOT open last used project on start

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, rad-studio

I'm new to Delphi, coming from Visual Studio it's a simple question (I guess): how do I prevent Delphi 10 Seattle to open last use project(group) when I start the IDE?

I've found some information about the .dsk file and what it does:

> The .dsk file records your current settings for:
>
> - Desktop layout
> - Breakpoints
> - Watch items
> - Files currently open in the IDE
>
> When you reopen the project later, the .dsk file is read, and your
>   desktop layout, your breakpoints, and your watches are all restored.
>   Also, all files that were opened when the project was closed are
>   opened again, regardless of whether they are used by the project.

I'm fine with that when I open a project. But please do not open it when I start the IDE. Mostly I want to start or open another project than the last one I was working on.
I've searched the options and the internet, but couldn't find a solution. Anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable "Project desktop" in the IDE Autosave options (Tools\Options\Envinroment options).

[image]

Comment: Just tested: this option doesn't take care of saving the layout and position of the tool windows like Refactorings, To-Do list. So I need to reposition them every day.
Delphi is good, but it's a pitty that the IDE lacks such a lot of (customization) functionalities compared to other IDE's like Visual Studio (Code). It feels like going back 10 years.

Answer (score 4):

> But please do not open it when I start the IDE. Mostly I want to start or open another project than the last one

Granted, I do no have Seattle at hands, I settled in XE2.
But try changing the shortcut.

> -np: No welcome page. Does not display the welcome page after starting the IDE. np also stands for No Project. Independently of Environment Options Project desktop the last opened project will not be opened

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options

---

> saving the layout and position of the tool windows like Refactorings,

That is what the "Layout" combo-box on the "Desktop" toolbar does. Unless you want different layouts in different projects. R-click over your IDE's tool buttons or go View|Toolbars menu to turn "Desktop" bar on. Alternatively use View|Desktops menu.

Comment: Thanks, +1. I literally just noticed that combo-box 5 minutes ago and thought "hey I guess that's what I'm looking for". After that I opened Stackoverflow and saw your answer. Telepathy? ;-)

Comment: well, my main point was command-line params for the shortcut, the combobox was just a bonus :-)